# Rally: Output from query to a file

Tags: java, task, rally

Sorry, new to Rally coding, java, etc.  I need to have a query showing tasks that are open output to a file so I can put it directly into somthing like OneNote.  I have the sample code to get the data...but can't figure out the output part.

Thanks in advance!

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.39/task?query=((Owner.Name = user@company.com) and (State != Completed))&order=Rank&fetch=true&stylesheet=/slm/doc/webservice/browser.xsl

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Linux or Unix system, you could do the following:

`curl -u username@company.com:topsecretpassword "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.39/task?query=((Owner.Name%20=%20%22username@company.com%22)%20and%20(State%20!=%20Completed))" >> MyTaskQuery.xml`

Note you'll need to encode the spaces using a %20 and the double quotes using a %22 per the above to get this to work.

Answer (score -1):

No need to be in Unix or Linux, curl is available for almos any platform.

Comment: True - they don't usually come preinstalled though :)

Comment: I don't either, I didn't down vote it. Here's an upvote for good measure.